# Call back URLs from array list and loop over them

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Good day everyone,

I am trying to scrape info from some products. The idea was to first get the URLs from the desired items and the make a 'for loop' and call back the URLs from the array, go to every single URL,scrape, close the tab, go to the next one. The problem is that I am not able to call properly back the URL from the array because every time when I use await page.goto it says 'Invalid URL...'.

Can anybody help me with some guidance.

Much appreciated!

Love,

Z.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');


(async function main() {
    try {

        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });


        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.goto('https://www.schroth.com/en/segments/racing/products/racing-belts.html');

        let div_selector = ".image_container";

        let list_length = await page.evaluate((sel) => {
            let elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(sel));
            return elements.length;
        }, div_selector);



        for (let i = 0; i < list_length; i++) {
            var href = await page.evaluate((l, sel) => {
                let elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(sel));
                let anchor = elements[l].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
                if (anchor) {
                    return anchor.href;
                } else {
                    return '';
                }


            }, i, div_selector);


            let urlList = [];

            urlList.push(href);

            console.log(urlList);




        }


        console.log('done');

        await browser.close();


    } catch (e) {

        console.log('error', e);

    }

})();
```

Comment: You are getting empty string from the first element, try more strict selector `let div_selector = "div.image_container";`.

Comment: I realized that after, later on I managed to loop through the URLs. The problem was that the first link was returning an empty string (' ') so naturally that I was receiving an error "Invalid URL...". Thank you for your comment.